# indent: space after function name in definition

Tags: c, function, definition, code-formatting, indentation

The code style guidelines I am required to follow mandate:

1. No space after the function name at function call sites
2. No space after the function name in function declarations/prototypes
3. Space after the function name in the function definition

I am trying to achieve this using [gnu `indent`](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/).

By default `indent` seems to add spaces after the function names in all the above cases.

If I supply the `-npcs` option, then the spaces are removed in all the above cases.

Is there any way I can get `indent` to give me spaces in the definition case, but no spaces in all the other cases?

I will also consider alternatives to `indent`.

Comment: I would use a combination of `indent` and `sed`...

Answer (score 1):

Indent does not appear to have those options.

Uncrustify (http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) has these options:

sp_func_proto_paren { Ignore, Add, Remove, Force }
    Add or remove space between function name and '(' on function declaration

sp_func_def_paren { Ignore, Add, Remove, Force }
    Add or remove space between function name and '(' on function definition

sp_func_call_paren { Ignore, Add, Remove, Force }
    Add or remove space between function name and '(' on function calls

It also has an associated gui tool : UniversalIndentGUI (http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/index.php).

HTH,